# I want today's date output for my procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
WITH dates
AS
  (SELECT (dt + level - 1) AS etadate
  FROM
    (SELECT TRUNC(DATE '2018-09-01', 'MM') - 1 AS dt FROM DUAL
    ) d
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - dt + 1
  )
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d.etadate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY')           AS DATEFORM,
  COALESCE(nsp.YNAME, LAG(nsp.YNAME IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate))         AS YNAME,
  COALESCE(nsp.CATEGORY, LAG(nsp.CATEGORY IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate))           AS CATEGORY,
  COALESCE(nsp.TYPE, LAG(nsp.TYPE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) AS TYPE,
  COALESCE(nsp.STOCK_BALANCE, LAG(nsp.STOCK_BALANCE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) AS STOCK_BALANCE
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN VW_NET_STOCK_POSITION nsp 
 ON d.etadate = TRUNC(nsp.LAST_UPD_IS)
```

and this is the output :

[image: OUTPUT]

Now, I want output only for today's date. The output should be last record of this output as today's date is 6th oct 2018.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data and your required output derived from that sample.

Comment: I don't see a stored procedure. You have posted a query.

Answer (score 1):

> need to repeat the previous transaction at place of null

The simplest way of doing that is to take your original query and wrap it in a filtering query:

```
select * from (
    WITH dates
    AS
      (SELECT (dt + level - 1) AS etadate
      FROM
        (SELECT TRUNC(DATE '2018-09-01', 'MM') - 1 AS dt FROM DUAL
        ) d
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - dt + 1
      )
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d.etadate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY')           AS DATEFORM,
      COALESCE(nsp.YNAME, LAG(nsp.YNAME IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate))         AS YNAME,
      COALESCE(nsp.CATEGORY, LAG(nsp.CATEGORY IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate))           AS CATEGORY,
      COALESCE(nsp.TYPE, LAG(nsp.TYPE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) AS TYPE,
      COALESCE(nsp.STOCK_BALANCE, LAG(nsp.STOCK_BALANCE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) AS STOCK_BALANCE
    FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN VW_NET_STOCK_POSITION nsp 
     ON d.etadate = TRUNC(nsp.LAST_UPD_IS)
)
where etadate = trunc(sysdate)
/
```

The performance of this might not be great in real life, depending on how much data you have in the underlying tables.

Comment: Please define *"it's not working"*. That's not an actionable insight. Do you get an error? Or just not the result you expect?

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess without sample data.

Comment: you can see my 'need to repeat the previous transaction at place of null' - question for more details

Comment: So you have no data for 6th October? Life would be a lot easier for everybody if you just posted some sample data and expected results instead of making us pull your requirements out of you.